# Open with, file association

Tags: autoit

I would like some help with autoit file association.

I want to have all text files(or any associated file) run my autoit script.

In windows you can right click a file > Open with > select my autoit program > Run

That part is easy, what i need help with is after that.
I need to get the text of the file that was just Opened.
or even just the location of the file.

Post if you need more info, I am still searching around for an answer.

~Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you associate a file extension with your exe, after double clicking the file with that extension your exe will receive the full path of that file in the command line.

*$CmdLineRaw* is the variable which is populated with complete command line.

```
$Read = FileRead($CmdLineRaw)
MsgBox(0,"File content is",$Read)
```

> This example associates the file extension "xyz" with the application
>   "Notepad".

```
FileExtAssoc("xyz", "NotePad.exe")

func FileExtAssoc($sExt, $sApplication)
    RunWait(@COMSPEC & " /c ASSOC ." & $sExt & "=ExTest", "", @SW_HIDE)
    RunWait(@COMSPEC & " /c FTYPE ExTest=" & $sApplication , "", @SW_HIDE)
    MsgBox(0,"File Extension Application Association",'"' & $sExt & '"is now asscoiated with "' & $sApplication & '"',3)
EndFunc
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, This is Completely what i was looking for!